# On the definition of $\mathrm{d}\omega$ for a $p$-form $\omega$ on a manifold $M$ in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

> Precisely the same considerations hold for forms. A function $\omega$ which assigns
> $\omega(x)\in\Lambda ^{p}(M_x)$ for each $x\in M$ is called a  **$p$-form on $M$**.
> If $f:W\to\mathbf{R}^{n}$ is a coordinate system, then $f^{*}\omega$ is a $p$-form
> on $W$; we *define* $\omega$ to be differentiable if $f^{*}\omega$ is. A $p$-form
> $\omega$ on $M$ can be written as $$
>  \omega =\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_p}\omega _{i_1,\ldots,i_p}\,\mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\,\mathrm{d}x^{i_p}
> .$$
> Here the functions $\omega _{i_1,\ldots,i_p}$ are defined only on $M$. The definition of
> $\mathrm{d}\omega$ given previously would make no sense here, since $D_j(\omega _{i_1,\ldots,i_p})$ has no meaning.
> Nevertheless, there is a reasonable way of defining $\mathrm{d}\omega$.

Spivak says the definition of $\mathrm{d}\omega$ for a $k$-form $\omega$ does not make sense on a manifold because $D_j(\omega_{i_1, \dots , i_p})$ has no meaning. Does it have no meaning because the function $\omega_{i_1, \dots , i_p}$ is defined only on $M$ so that we have consider the tangent space but $\mathrm{d}\omega$ is taking partial derivatives of the function based on the unit vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of the tangent space?

Comment: I do not see any "previous" definition of $\mathrm{d}\omega$. I guess he defined the differential on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and he is now trying to make sense of $\mathrm{d}\omega$ on $M$. I say so because I think $D_j(\omega_{i_1,\dots,i_n})$ are partial derivatives on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so he should define partial derivatives on $M$.

Comment: The "previous" definition refers to the definition when you have a form defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now he is trying to extend the concept to the more general situation of a form defined on a manifold. Since we do not know what partial derivatives mean on a manifold, we resort to coordinates to give a meaning to the concept. Not only we define the concept of differentiable using coordinates, but the derivative as well. After this paragraph, he will define $d\omega$ using partial derivatives of the functions $\omega_{i,j,k\dots}$ as functions on $W$.